# php not receiving variables from as3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

This is the weirdest thing I have ever experienced as a flasher. the php programer says that my code does not pass it any variables (the variables Name and email). Here is the as3. 
I'd put the php but the programer tells me the php has nothing to do with it, I am not addressing the upload file, the address is correct (when I type it in)

```
texti.visible = false; 

var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader;
var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://[someadress]/upload.php");
var urlvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;    

    //var urlreq:urlreq = new URLRequest("https://localhost/upload/upload.php");

    var imageTypes:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg,  *.png)", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png");

    var allTypes:Array = new Array(imageTypes);

    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();

    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, syncVariables);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

    btn_browse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browseBox);
    btn_upload.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, uploadVars);        

    function browseBox(event:MouseEvent):void {
        fileRef.browse(allTypes);
    }

    function uploadVars(event:MouseEvent):void {            
        urlvars.Name = "somename"; 
        urlvars.Email = "some@someEmail.com"; 
        //urlvars.fb_id = Main.facebook1;
        urlvars.picname = fileRef.name;
        trace(urlvars.Name);
        trace(urlvars.Email);
        loader.load(urlreq);
        fileRef.upload(urlreq);
        btn_upload.visible = true;
    }

    function syncVariables(event:Event):void {
         texti.text = "" + fileRef.name;
         //blocker.visible = false;
         btn_upload.visible = true;         
    }

    function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("h1");

        var bytestoLoad:Number = loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
        var numberLoaded:Number = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
        if (bytestoLoad == numberLoaded)
        {
        gotoAndStop(2);

        trace(fileRef.name);                

        t_status.gotoAndPlay(2);
        btn_upload.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, uploadVars);
        btn_browse.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browseBox);

        }   
        else
        {               
            trace("wtf?");              
        }

    }

    function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
         trace("inprogress")
    }
```

any help would be appreciated as I have been changing minor stuff in the code for hours now and still no progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot one line of code right before you call the load:

```
urlreq.data = urlvars;
```

You need to assign the vars to the request.

Comment: before call the load? as in before 
`loader.load(urlreq); `  ?

Comment: yes, the vars need to be assigned to the urlreq before you call the load

Comment: Adobe Docs:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: thanks, I'll test this tomorrow at work and get back with an answer if it worked :)

Comment: Don't you mean urlreq.data = urlvars

Comment: ha - yes, yes I did.  Nice catch on the typo.

Comment: it wooorks, it worked even on the localhost, I got the var I wanted, real jobsavers, thanks a lot :) how do I rate you or something

Comment: thanks!  you can up vote this answer when you get a few more points, that will be fine.  Glad I could help